# finding supremum

Tags: real-analysis

I am going through analysis paper and I cannot find a way to start this question:
$f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be a continuous function with $f(0) >0$ and $$\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)=\lim_{ x\to -\infty} f(x) = 0.$$

1. Show that $f$ is bounded.
2. Let $A= \sup\{f(x)\mid x \in \Bbb R\}$. Show that there is a point $c$ such that $f(c)=A$.

Basically i showed the first part  using definition of limit tending to zero and set epsilon as M>0.

Comment: Thus |f(x)|<M .
However, I am unable to start the second part.
I am always stuck with questions involving supremum though i understand the basic idea.
Please help

Comment: Hint: $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ so by the Extreme Value Theorem ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first consider (i): Since $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$, we find a $M > 0$, such that $\vert f(x) \vert < 1$ for all $x > M$. In the same way we find a $M' < 0$, such that $\vert f(x) \vert < 1$ for all $x < M'$. Now you we are only left to show that $f$ is bounded on the compact interval $[M', M]$. Now it is an easy application of the extreme value theorem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem).

(ii) Here you can use the same idea: You find a $M > 0$, such that $\vert f(x) \vert < A$ for each $x > M$, and you find a $M' < 0$, such that $\vert f(x) \vert < A$ for each $x < M'$. Observe that $A > 0$, since $f(0) > 0$. Now again, have a look at the extreme value theoream.

Comment: why should |f(x)| be less than 1?

Comment: Because $f(x) \to 0$ for $x \to \infty$. Remember the meaning of $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$. It means that for each $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $M > 0$, such that $\vert f(x) - 0 \vert < \epsilon$ for all $x > M$.

Comment: then you set epsilon to be 1 for the specific M ?

Comment: You just set $\epsilon =1$. Then from the definition of the limit, there exists a $M > 0$ (which depends on the chosen $\epsilon$), such that $\vert f(x) - 0 \vert < 1$ for all $x > M$.

Answer (score 1):

Extreme value theorem - use the fact that the limit as $x$ tends to $\pm \infty$ is zero to show that all function values for $x$ outside some closed interval are less than $f(0)$, then use the EVT on that interval to conclude that the maximum value is achieved.